# why do i get the error invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char"' in c language

Tags: c

Here is a struct containing the variables

```
    struct theFile{

        FILE *fPointer;
        char *fileItems[];
        int count;
    }myFile;
```

I'm wondering why I get the error invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' when I have my code like this

```
    void saveFile(){

        myFile.fPointer = fopen("mileage.txt", "r");
        char item;
        int i = 0;

        while (!feof(myFile.fPointer)){
            item = fgetc(myFile.fPointer);
            while (item != ',' || item != ' '){
                myFile.fileItems[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
                strcpy(myFile.fileItems[i], item);
                i++;
                item = fgetc(myFile.fPointer);              
            }
            myFile.count++;
        }
    }
```

but I don't have the error when I have item as a pointer

```
     void saveFile(){

        myFile.fPointer = fopen("mileage.txt", "r");
        char *item;
        int i = 0;

        while (!feof(myFile.fPointer)){
            *item = fgetc(myFile.fPointer);
            while (*item != ',' || *item != ' '){
                myFile.fileItems[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
                strcpy(myFile.fileItems[i], item);
                i++;
                *item = fgetc(myFile.fPointer);             
            }
            myFile.count++;
        }
}
```

Comment: because it is invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*'!

Comment: `char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src);` is the declaration of strcpy function, here second parameter is `const char` type.

Comment: `strcpy` is use for copy string  (in `c` array of char) not `char`. here `item` only `char` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues that I see:

Issue 1:

```
struct theFile{
    FILE *fPointer;
    char *fileItems[];
    int count;
}myFile;
```

is not valid. The flexible array member has to be the last member of the `struct`. Use

```
struct theFile{
    FILE *fPointer;
    int count;
    char fileItems[]; // This is an array of char not an array of char*.
}myFile;
```

instead.

Issue 2:

```
strcpy(myFile.fileItems[i], item);
```

is not valid since the second argument is of type `char` not `char*`. That's what the compiler is telling you.

Issue 3:

Your code needs to be updated for the flexible way you want to keep adding input data to `myFile`.

```
void saveFile()
{
   int item;
   int i = 0;

   myFile.fPointer = fopen("mileage.txt", "r");

   // Deal with error condition.
   if ( myFile.fPointer == NULL )
   {
       // Add an appropriate error message.
       printf("Unable to open '%s' for reading.\n", "mileage.txt");
       return;
   }

   myFile.fileItems = malloc(i+1);

   while ((item = fgetc(myFile.fPointer)) != EOF )
   {
      if (item != ',' || item != ' ')
      {
         myFile.fileItems = realloc(myFile.fileItems, i+1);
         myFile.fileItems[i] = item;
         i++;
      }
   }
   myFile.count = i;

   // You need to call fclose(myFile.fPointer) somewhere.
   // I am not sure what's the best place in your program to do that.
   // This function might as well be that place.
   fclose(myFile.fPointer);
   myFile.fPointer = NULL;
}
```

Issue 4:

The name `saveFile` seems a bit misleading since you are not saving anything to a file. `readFile` sounds like a better name to me.

Answer (score 0):

In strcpy is a char * argument. In first case you are passing the character variable. So it is not accepting that and throwing the error.

```
char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src);
```

So when you are using the pointer that time it accepting that.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing single characters with strings. Also, *both* versions of the code are writing to unallocated memory.

Rather than try to explain this in complete detail, I'm going to suggest you go back to the book(s) you're learning C from, because you've misunderstood some really fundamental things here.